# subview isn't moving after button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm new to programming for iOS and I have run into a problem that I can't seem to solve.

I have a `UIViewController` that has 2 `UIButton` objects in it. There are also 3 `UIView` subviews. 2 of these subviews switch from hidden to visible when their corresponding button is clicked. The third subview moves to a point that is calculated when one of the button is clicked. In the subview there is also a `UILabel` where the text changes based on which button is clicked.

The problem I am having that that the subview that is supposed to move doesn't move unless I click the button twice. In the process of debugging, I found that the subview will move if I don't change the text on the label.

```
- (void) load_pH
{
    float uph_x = 11.44;
    int uph_y = 76;
    int x_offset = 530;
    int y_offset = 540;

    self.view1.alpha = 0;
    self.view2.alpha = 1;

    CGRect btFrame = self.graphView.frame;

    btFrame.origin.x = (int)([APPDELEGATE.calculations.value1 floatValue] * uph_x) + x_offset;
    btFrame.origin.y = (int)(y_offset - ([APPDELEGATE.calculations.value1 floatValue] - 5) * uph_y);
    NSLog(@"new dimens: %f.0, %f.0", btFrame.origin.x, btFrame.origin.y);
    self.graphView.frame = btFrame;

    self.graphValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pH= %@", [self.formatter stringFromNumber:@([APPDELEGATE.calculations.value1 floatValue])]];

}
```

I assume it has something to do with layout but I haven't been able to figure it out so far.

Comment: Does the `UIView` have constraints within the storyboard? You might be trying to move it outside of these constraints.

Comment: It has a width and height constraint but that is it. I also tried it without these constraints with no success.

Comment: Have you double checked that your frame calculations _actually_ result in change of frame? Put an NSLog before you set the frame to read the old frame value. Without knowing what `[APPDELEGATE.calculations.value1 floatValue]` is, it's hard to help.

Comment: It does result in a position change. The change occurs if I click the button twice or if I comment out the line where where I am setting self.graphValue.text. The value is calculated but for my test it is moving between x:392 y:373 and x:410 and y:422

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue but setting `self.graphView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;` before I set my frame.